# 10 week Havachon menace, tantrum crying/howling in crate and playpen constantly, compounded by biting

Tags: dogs, behavior, training, toilet-training, crate

We have several problems.

**Main Problem: Howling/crying bloody murder**

What happens:

- Howls, barks angrily, jumping up at the door of crate/barrier
- Sometimes bites/gnaws on barrier/crate

Compounds other problems:

- Tantrum "exercise" causes him to poop in the crate, makes a huge mess

  - Cannot clean crate until he stops tantrum either or it reinforces tantrum
- He does this for 20mins to an hour or more, sound is awful obviously
- Cannot keep him to regular feeding/exercise schedule because cannot give him attention during his tantrums

Occurs when:

- The moment I close door to crate or playpen
- The moment he cannot get to me readily
- The moment he realizes I'm home from work

Attempts to change this:

- Stood right in front of him or in the room so he could see me (didn't work)

  - Often he ramps it up into full bloody murder mode (tantrum)
- Covered crate with blanket, partially and wholly like "cave" (didn't work)
- Added ticking clock "heartbeat" (didn't work)
- Added ipod with classical music (didn't work)
- Added high-value treats to inside of crate (partially works)

  - He will gnaw rawhide for a while after his tantrum

    - Compounds new problem: bitey when I try to keep the treats in the crate
    - He wants to take them out, dart in and out to get treats
- Exercised him with multiple walks per day (unsure if working)

  - He seems to still have energy to tantrum/howl
- Tried clapping (only temporarily works)

  - Only works temporarily to surprise him from his tantrum, a split second later he starts up again
- Only giving him attention/showing him my presence when he's quiet/calmed (unsure if working)

  - Due to all of the above (and below), I'm not sure this makes a difference
  - He howls even longer if he sees me in the room, worse if I'm looking at him
  - He howls if he sees me leaving
  - He howls if I ignore him/do not give him physical contact

**Second Problem: Biting**

What happens:

- Bites hands, wrists, clothes, my shoes as I'm wearing them

Compounds other problems:

- Unsure how to handle him for cleaning/travel
- Unsure how to play with him (healthy tug games) if he keeps this up

Occurs when:

- When I try to force treats to stay in crate, not be taken out
- When he gets too excited as we play tug
- When I am not paying attention to him

Attempts to change this:

- "Yelped" in pain, stood and ignored him for 10-30 seconds, before playing/paying attention to him again (didn't work)

  - Yes, he gets startled, but he just distracts himself with other stuff or jumps and nips at my shoes/legs/jeans
- Growling/shouting a "NO!" (never works)

  - He is unafraid of any sort of reprimand, no matter how loud or low my voice is pitched
- "Flick on nose" move right after he does this(doesn't work)

  - Compounds problem: he just bites even more, he thinks I'm playing

**Limitations: Time**

- I read the entire AKC "ideal" schedule for puppy feeding/exercise/playtimes
- Unrealistic - I have a full time job
- Currently I take him out/play/exercise him when I can in mornings, lunch breaks, after work, and evenings before bed

I have lost so much sleep taking care of him. And I want to do this right, but all the information I've found is just contradicting each other.
Help!

Edit: I've re-organized this so it's easier to read.

Comment: Welcome to Pets Stack Exchange! :) Are there any questions that you've looked through that are similar to yours? I know we have a lot of [questions about dogs and crate training](https://pets.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdog%5D+%5Btraining%5D+crate).

Comment: I have, thank you! I added everything on this post because I think they kind of stem from the crate training though. Most of the guides I've found only talk about one situation at a time.

He gets angry/tantrum-like and bitey when I crate him, and especially when I try to keep treats inside the crate to encourage him to think of it as a happy place. There also isn't a lot of talk about how to deal with potty training when he's having a tantrum in the crate (I can't reward him by giving him attention/taking him out; but he can't stay in there forever!). He howls/cries for hours at a time.